# write error: broken pipe with lemonbar script

Tags: pipe, lemonbar, bspwm

I'm trying to pipe a bar script into lemonbar in bspwm.

In my bspwmrc I have:

```
~/.config/bspwm/lemonbar.sh | lemonbar -p
```

lemonbar.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

clock() {
    date +%H:%M:%S
}

while true; do
    echo "%{c}$(clock)"
    sleep 1;
done
```

Everything works as expected, execpt when I exit bspwm I get:

```
line 12: echo: write error: Broken pipe
```

Obviously the error has something to do with the echo on line 12 but I can't figure out exactly what

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce this issue. For me it is working. Make sure you put the script line at the end of *bspwmrc* and add a **&** at the end. [image: You can see it working here.]

I have my own setup with lemonbar. See at the top of the screen, time is echoed from your script and whenever I restart/exit from **bspwm**, I don't get some errors.